# Hotmail not receiving emails from a script, but works from the server

Tags: scripting, python, smtp

I have a working mail server running Debian stable, the following elements are working.

1. SPF
2. DKIM
3. rDNS

My IP is not listed in any backlist, I used: mxtoolbox.com for all this.

My problem: Sending emails to hotmail with a python script sometimes doesn't work. The mail gets sent but the recipient doesn't get it (or goes to spam). This doesn't ever happen when sending to my account so I don't even know what happens.

This is the script (Maybe I'm missing a header?)
Consider that, at the moment, security is not a concern (I'm not checking the parameters at all)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

if len(sys.argv)!=3:
        print "2 parameter, mail subject (quoted)"
        sys.exit(1)

sender = 'sender@domain.com.ar'
receiver = sys.argv[1] 

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = sys.argv[2]
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver

with open('mailtext', 'r') as content_file:
    message= content_file.read()

msg.attach(MIMEText(message,'html'))
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

This is my mail.log for the mail I sent

```
Nov 10 14:20:59 domain postfix/smtpd[11743]: connect from domain.com.ar[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 14:20:59 domain postfix/smtpd[11743]: 2668943282: client=domain.com.ar[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 14:21:00 domain postfix/cleanup[11749]: 2668943282: message-id=
Nov 10 14:21:00 domain postfix/qmgr[4185]: 2668943282: from=, size=836, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 14:21:00 domain postfix/smtpd[11743]: disconnect from domain.com.ar[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain postfix/smtpd[11761]: connect from domain.com.ar[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain postfix/smtpd[11761]: 9F19843285: client=domain.com.ar[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain postfix/cleanup[11749]: 9F19843285: message-id=
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain postfix/qmgr[4185]: 9F19843285: from=, size=1262, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain postfix/smtpd[11761]: disconnect from domain.com.ar[127.0.0.1]
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain amavis[10275]: (10275-15) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, MYNETS/MYUSERS LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:45027 [127.0.0.1]  -> , Queue-ID: 2668943282, Message-ID: , mail_id: 16V7UTH-mVAO, Hits: -7.345, size: 835, queued_as: 9F19843285, 4471 ms
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain postfix/smtp[11756]: 2668943282: to=, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=5.6, delays=1.1/0.01/0.01/4.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9F19843285)
Nov 10 14:21:04 domain postfix/qmgr[4185]: 2668943282: removed
Nov 10 14:21:06 domain postfix/smtp[11762]: 9F19843285: to=, relay=mx1.hotmail.com[65.54.188.94]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.01/0.02/0.86/0.51, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250   Queued mail for delivery)
Nov 10 14:21:06 domain postfix/qmgr[4185]: 9F19843285: removed
```

Anything obvious I'm missing?